# Nested Collection.stream() in for loop time and space complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have an algorithm of which I need to find the space and time complexity.

```
public static List<Integer> myList(String niceKeys, String badKeys,
                                                List<Integer> myIds,
                                                List<String> reviews, int k) {
        List<String> niceKeyToken = Arrays.asList(niceKeys.split(" "));
        List<String> badKeyToken = Arrays.asList(badKeys.split(" "));
        Map<Integer, Integer> niceReview = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < reviews.size(); i++) {
            int myId = myIds.get(i);
            List<String> review = Arrays.asList(reviews.get(i).split(" "));
            int currentNice = (int) review.stream()
                    .filter(token -> niceKeyToken.contains(token))
                    .count();
            int currentBad = (int) review.stream()
                    .filter(token -> badKeyToken.contains(token))
                    .count();
            int total = currentNice * 3 + currentBad * -1;
            int previous = niceReview.getOrDefault(myId, 0);
            niceReview.put(myId, previous + total);
        }
        List<Integer> finalList = niceReview.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
                .limit(k)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return finalList;
    }
```

If size of reviews is **M**, it should be O(M).
But then we are doing `review.stream()` inside the `for loop` which should increase the complexity but I am not sure how much ? And what would be the space complexity ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If reviews size is M and review size is let's say N, niceKeyToken - X, badKeyToken - Y, time complexity should be O(M * (N * X + N * Y)), i am not so sure about space complexity, you are working with strings, so i'd say it depends on the size of the strings. I think it would be best if you do some benchmarking with big test data.

First about niceKeyToken and badKeyToken - you use them only for a search, so List is a bad choice for data structure, you should be using a HashSet. Time complexity for ArrayList.contains() is O(N), while for HashSet - O(1).

Second about the streams - you are streaming the review list twice, once for nice keys, then twice for bad keys. You are only doing simple filtering with the stream, i think streaming is an overkill for this situation, you can get away with a single loop. Streams can be expensive and slow sometimes(again benchmarking would be best).

Third stems from the second point - no need to save review in a list, if you are only iterating it, an array is enough.

This is how i would do it:

```
public static List<Integer> myList(String niceKeys, String badKeys, List<Integer> myIds, List<String> reviews, int k) {
        //HashSet contains method returns in constant time, for list, if the element, you are looking for is last
        //potentially you have to traverse entire collection
        Set<String> niceKeyToken = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(niceKeys.split(" ")));
        Set<String> badKeyToken = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(badKeys.split(" ")));
        Map<Integer, Integer> niceReview = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < reviews.size(); i++) {
          int myId = myIds.get(i);
          //array would suffice here, only iterating the elements
          String[] review = reviews.get(i).split(" ");
          int currentNice = 0;
          int currentBad = 0;
          //single iteration, instead of twice with streams
          for (int j = 0; j < review.length; j++) {
            String token = review[j];
            //quick lookup for token, because of HashSet
            if (niceKeyToken.contains(token)) {
              currentNice++;
            }
            //quick lookup for token, because of HashSet
            if (badKeyToken.contains(token)) {
              currentBad++;
            }
          }
          int total = currentNice * 3 + currentBad * -1;
          int previous = niceReview.getOrDefault(myId, 0);
          niceReview.put(myId, previous + total);
        }
        return niceReview.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
                .limit(k)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
      }
```

This should reduce time complexity to O(M * N).

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks.